# Bootstrap fixed col-md-4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I would like to set a **bootstrap column position to fixed** (`col-md-4`).
It's about a shop, divided into 2 columns :

1. Shop content (very long & scrollable) `col-md-8`
2. Cart content (pretty short & fixed so when you scroll the shop content, the cart content always remains visible) `col-md-4`

I don't know what is the proper way to do that in bootstrap.

This is my expected behavior: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/08/1456677164-neededbehavior.jpg

For now, I've tried to set the `col-md-4` position to fixed with `css` property, it kind of works but not completely.

As you can see in [this picture](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/08/1456677164-gotbehavior.jpg), when I set the `col-md-4` position to fixed, its width (33% for `col-md-4`) is wider than what it should be.

Actually, `col-md-4` has a 33% width css property from bootstrap that is calculated from its parent container.

But when the position is set to fixed, for some reasons, the 33% is calculated from the screen view width. So if the resolution width would be 2500px, it wouldn't be 33% of the container 1170px but 33% of the screen size 2500px.
So the `col-md-4` is wider than expected and is overflowing the container.

I guess I could recalculate the correct width in javascript but I wonder if there is a proper way to do that in bootstrap (I guess so).

Comment: did you put your content under a container? or maybe your content is to big and it overflow, you might one to use `overflow: hidden;` for the cart style

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case i would not use Bootstrap col classes. It would look better with something like:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="cart"></div>

.content {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 200px;
}

.cart {
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Bootstrap is nice, but don't forget, that col class is a floated item. And in your case this approach is not that suitable, as you expect your .cart sidebar to be fixed and do not respect any float rules.